# Position of invalidateLater in an observer

Tags: r, shiny

Does the position of invalidateLater inside an observer matter? That is, is there a difference between this:

```r
observe({
  invalidateLater(100)
  compute_long_operation()
})
```

and this:

```r
observe({
  compute_long_operation()
  invalidateLater(100)
})
```

In other words, is the time to invalidation computed when invalidateLater is called or at the end of the observer expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it and see that the timer starts when you invoke `invalidateLater`, not when the block exits.

## invalidateLater *first*

```r
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      message(Sys.time())
      invalidateLater(4000)
      Sys.sleep(5)
    })
  }
)
# 2024-02-18 17:50:20.882246
# 2024-02-18 17:50:25.884962
# 2024-02-18 17:50:30.887552
# 2024-02-18 17:50:35.89
```

Each message spanned exactly 5 seconds, suggesting that the `invalidateLater` started its timer before `Sys.sleep` started.

## invalidateLater *last*

```r
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      message(Sys.time())
      Sys.sleep(5)
      invalidateLater(4000)
    })
  }
)
# 2024-02-18 17:51:02.759535
# 2024-02-18 17:51:11.761428
# 2024-02-18 17:51:20.763431
# 2024-02-18 17:51:29.765284
```

Each message spanned 5+4 seconds, confirming that the `invalidateLater` starts its timer when you call it.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected as much based on the behavior of my app but wasn't clever enough to think about making a nice timed example like yours.